# Script only changing document.body.contentEditable to false and not true

Tags: javascript

```
javascript:if(document.body.contentEditable == false){document.body.contentEditable = true;}else{document.body.contentEditable = false;} void 0;
```

it appears that all it does is make it false.

Comment: [Under what circumstances may I add "urgent" or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/326569/under-what-circumstances-may-i-add-urgent-or-other-similar-phrases-to-my-quest) - tl;dr: never

Comment: `"false" != false`

Comment: Elabortate please @epascarello

Comment: `console.log(document.body.contentEditable, "==", false, document.body.contentEditable == false, document.body.contentEditable == 'false')`

Comment: @​epascarello thank you this was way More helpful then @Andreas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason it is always changing it to false is primarily because `document.body.contentEditable` is going to be a string (i.e., `"true"`, `"false"`, `"inherit"`). Your code just needs to include quotes around `true` and `false` in your conditional for it to work as intended:

```js
javascript:if(document.body.contentEditable == "false"){document.body.contentEditable = "true";}else{document.body.contentEditable = "false";} void 0;
```

Answer (score 2):

Since `contenteditable` is an `element` *attribute*, it is best read, set, or changed, using the `.getAttribute` and `.setAttribute` properties of the element's object.

The snippet shows the syntax used to read and set the attribute, using a working example where a button toggles editability of a paragraph element.

```js
let editBox = document.getElementById("edit-field");

document.getElementsByTagName('button')[0].addEventListener('click', event =>{

    if (editBox.getAttribute("contenteditable")=="true") {
    editBox.setAttribute("contenteditable", "false");
    console.log("switched to not editable");
  } else {
    editBox.setAttribute("contenteditable", "true");
    console.log("switched to editable");
  }
}) // end button click;
```

```css
#edit-field {
  width: 300px;
  height: 100px;
  background: yellow;
}
```

```html
<p id="edit-field" contenteditable="false"> I am editable (sometimes)</p>
<button>toggle editability </button>
```

Comment: by the way  Sometimes it is not editable but thank you

Comment: Could you let me know under what circumstances it fails? I can't reproduce any examples. I included the console messages to show when a click was registered and, if there's a click it should toggle. Thanks.